# How can I rewrite several batch commands more efficiently?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way to consolidate the following code into a single line of code?

I am setting environment variables and configurations in a bat file.

Specifically, I need to copy 1 source file into variable targets.

For example I need to copy 1.gif to a client folder depending on what they have: M020, M030,..  M080.

Currently I have:

```
copy "<source>" "targetM020"
copy "<source>" "targetM030"
copy "<source>" "targetM040"
copy "<source>" "targetM050"
```

etc...

Comment: some users have a M020 folder in which the gif needs to be copied to. Others have M30; other have M040; others have M050, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a FOR command

```
FOR %%i in (...) DO COPY "<source>" %%i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FOR command and specify the list of targets in a string. You'll have to look up the exact syntax, but this will get you started:

```
FOR /F "delims=," %%D IN ("targetM020,targetM030,targetM040,targetM050") DO COPY "<SOURCE>" "%%D"
```

Comment: This is good Metaphor.. instead of /F, I use /D. The other problem is that my target(s) are each too long. Not sure I can string 300 characters in one line?

Comment: you can use a text file instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for different targets - the command line can be around 8KB in XP and later.

```
for %%a in ("targetM020" "targetM030" "targetM040" "targetM050") do copy "c:\folder\file.gif" "%%~a"
```

if they share a common target folder then you can use this style:

```
for %%a in ("targetM020" "targetM030" "targetM040" "targetM050") do copy "c:\folder\file.gif" "d:\backup\folder ABC\%%~a"
```